# Get current value of Animated.Value, React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to animate View with interpolate. I'd like to get a current value of my Animated.Value, but don't know how. I didn't understand how to do it with [React-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#responding-to-the-current-animation-value).

```js
this.state = {
      translateAnim: new Animated.Value(0)
}
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('Accelerometer', function (data) {
  console.log(this.state.translateAnim);
  // returns an object, but I need a value in current moment
}
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I find out, how to get a value:

```js
this.state.translateAnim.addListener(({value}) => this._value = value);
```

EDIT

to log a value I do the following:

```js
console.log(this.state.translateAnim._value)
```

Comment: With tsc give me an warning: `The property '_value' does not exist in the 'Value' type.`

Comment: @jose920405 did you ever figure out how to get this to compile with tsc?

Comment: This observer is documented at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.5/animatedvalue - they say " This is useful because there is no way to synchronously read the value because it might be driven natively."

Comment: Can use //@ts-ignore comment to ignore tsc warnings for a line

Comment: in React native version 0.59.1 it says, **addListener** is not a function. Correct me if I am wrong. I couldn't console the animated value by any means.

Answer (score 33):

This also works for me...

```js
const headerHeight = new Animated.Value(0);
```

After some manipulation....

```js
console.log(headerHeight.__getValue())
```

It feels hackish but it gets the job done...

Comment: WARNING: This will always return 0 if userNativeDriver is true.

Comment: Hoe do you add addListener in functional components?

Comment: @roz333 I wrote a hook to handle this in my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/61260706/1294382

Comment: `useNativeDriver` and not `userNativeDriver` [doc](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/02/14/using-native-driver-for-animated#how-do-i-use-this-in-my-app)

Answer (score 33):

For the people with typescript.

```ts
console.log((this.state.translateAnim as any)._value);
```

It worked for me to full tsc as any.

Comment: thanks you, i don't know why TS showing this error

Answer (score 13):

```
Number.parseInt(JSON.stringify(translateAnim))
```

It works on React Hook

Comment: Many thanks! This works for me when i try to convert type of `Animated.AnimatedMultiplication` to `number`

Comment: `parseInt(JSON.stringify(translateAnim))` works too, without `Number` infront

Comment: Thanks this worked for me!
`const scrollYPosition = Number(JSON.stringify(scrollY))`

Answer (score 7):

edit: CAUTION - MAY CAUSE SEVERE PERFORMANCE ISSUES. I have not been able to figure out why, but if you use this for 30+ simultaneous animations your framerate will slow to a crawl. It seems like it must be a bug in react-native with Animated.Value addListener as I don't see anything wrong with my code, it only sets a listener which sets a ref which should be instantaneous.

Here's a hook I came up with to do it without resorting to accessing private internal values.

```
/**
 * Since there's no (official) way to read an Animated.Value synchronously this is the best solution I could come up with
 * to have access to an up-to-date copy of the latest value without sacrificing performance.
 * 
 * @param animatedValue the Animated.Value to track
 * @param initial Optional initial value if you know it to initialize the latest value ref before the animated value listener fires for the first time
 *
 * returns a ref with the latest value of the Animated.Value and a boolean ref indicating if a value has been received yet
 */
const useAnimatedLatestValueRef = (animatedValue: Animated.Value, initial?: number) => {
    //If we're given an initial value then we can pretend we've received a value from the listener already
    const latestValueRef = useRef(initial ?? 0)
    const initialized = useRef(typeof initial == "number")

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = animatedValue.addListener((v) => {
            //Store the latest animated value
            latestValueRef.current = v.value
            //Indicate that we've recieved a value
            initialized.current = true
        })

        //Return a deregister function to clean up
        return () => animatedValue.removeListener(id)

        //Note that the behavior here isn't 100% correct if the animatedValue changes -- the returned ref
        //may refer to the previous animatedValue's latest value until the new listener returns a value
    }, [animatedValue])


    return [latestValueRef, initialized] as const
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like private property. But works for me. Helpful for debugging, but wouldn't recommend using it in production.

```
translateAnim._value
```

Comment: why wouldn't you recommend using it in prod?

Comment: They would have made it public if it was recommended for production use.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense! I ended up storing the value in a Ref to avoid any unexpected behavior. Thanks for the warning :D

Answer (score 0):

I actually found another way to get the value (not sure if it is a recommended way, but it works).

Use `JSON.stringify()`  on the animated value and use Number on the result to convert it into Number.

E.g,

```
const animatedVal = new Animated.Value(0);

const jsanimated = JSON.stringify(animatedVal);

const finalResult = Number(jsanimated)
```