# How do I log an Animated Value on each update in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

I have used the Animated Scrollview and I'm using the`y` value from the `contentOffset` in `onScroll` prop which I have set to the state to manipulate the other properties. I have also set the `useNativeDriver to true`. However ***I want to check the y value in the state as it updates***. How do I do this? If there are multiple ways to do this it'll be nice to know since I'm very new to this. **I did check out the addListener method**, but failed to implement it as it was only logging the initial value which is 0. I also checked out the`_getValue` method but that doesn't work when `useNativeDriver` is set to true.

You can also share a link to the resources or code snippets as well for me to refer.

Please let me know if I have missed out on any detail in the question. Thank you.

I referred to this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41934928/10841628

My attempt:

```
state={ y:new Animated.Value(0) }
componentDidMount(){
    this.state.y.addListener(({value}) => this._value = value)
}
componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log(this.state.y._value)
}
```

And the Scrollview:

```
<Animated.ScrollView 
   scrollEventThrottle={16}
   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
   onScroll={Animated.event(
      [
          {
              nativeEvent: {
                  contentOffset: { y }
              }
          }
      ],
      { useNativeDriver: true }
   )}
/>
```

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/animatedvalue#addlistener

Comment: Please show your attempt to use `addListener` that way we can help you debug.

Comment: Sure. I have added the snippet