# I am trying to add progress bar in my code I have found this following relevant code so i need a converted code like class to function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, progress-bar, react-functional-component

But the problem is I beginner at class component need that one into function component.

```js
 import React, {Component} from 'react';  
    import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Animated} from 'react-native';  
      
    export default class App extends Component {  
        state={  
            progressStatus: 0,  
        }  
        anim = new Animated.Value(0);  
        componentDidMount(){  
            this.onAnimate();  
        }  
        onAnimate = () =>{  
            this.anim.addListener(({value})=> {  
                this.setState({progressStatus: parseInt(value,10)});  
            });  
            Animated.timing(this.anim,{  
                 toValue: 100,  
                 duration: 50000,  
            }).start();  
        }  
      render() {  
        return (  
          <View style={styles.container}>  
                <Animated.View  
                    style={[  
                        styles.inner,{width: this.state.progressStatus +"%"},  
                    ]}  
                />  
                <Animated.Text style={styles.label}>  
                        {this.state.progressStatus }%  
                </Animated.Text>  
          </View>  
        );  
      }  
    }  
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
        container: {  
        width: "100%",  
        height: 40,  
        padding: 3,  
        borderColor: "#FAA",  
        borderWidth: 3,  
        borderRadius: 30,  
        marginTop: 200,  
        justifyContent: "center",  
      },  
      inner:{  
        width: "100%",  
        height: 30,  
        borderRadius: 15,  
        backgroundColor:"green",  
      },  
      label:{  
        fontSize:23,  
        color: "black",  
        position: "absolute",  
        zIndex: 1,  
        alignSelf: "center",  
      }  
    })
```

It should move from left to right for 60-second animation with background color and the most important part is inside this progress bar I need to pass view and the text to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the same code but in a function (https://snack.expo.dev/@heytony01/eager-toffee) however this one doesn't dynamically update the text. You could probably figure it out here ([Get current value of Animated.Value, React-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932345/get-current-value-of-animated-value-react-native))